# django six 1.10.0 no module named http_client error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm developing with Django 1.5.5 and I recently installed django-rest-framework and django-rest-auth. I had to upgrade my six installation from 1.6.0 to >1.9.0 to make it work, but now I'm getting this error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.230:8080/
Django Version:     1.5.5
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named http_client

Exception Location:     /home/XXXX/www/PROJECT/buildout/eggs/djangorestframework-3.2.4-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/response.py in <module>, line 11
Python Executable:  /home/XXXX/www/PROJECT/buildout/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, [Rest Framework requires Django 1.5.6+](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements).

It isn't your install of `six` which is too old, it is the version of `six` that Django includes as `django.utils.six`.